# Rake equivalent to make -k (--keep-going)

Tags: makefile, rake, equivalent

By default Rake will stop at the first exception raised.

There doesn't seem to be a command line equivalent to make -k, is there any way to do it programmaticaly?

Comment: Solved my problem in a similar way suggested by @jmonteiro:

    rule '.o' => ['.c'] do |t|  
      begin  
        sh "cc #{t.source} -c -o #{t.name}"   
      rescue RuntimeError => e  
        if keep_going?  
          next 0  
        else  
          raise e  
        end  
      end  
    end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `--keep-going` in `rake` (and I think that's fine). The only way I can think of is to wrap your Rakefile with `begin; rescue; end`, but it won't make it "keep going" -- it will simply ensure that your `rake`'s execution return is `0`.

```
begin
  # Former Rakefile code goes here
rescue
  puts $!.inspect
end
```

I believe that "keep going" isn't possible since when you `raise` something you already changed your algorithm's flow -- i.e. don't try to solve your problem by ignoring Exceptions.